# Проблема с раздачей статических файлов в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Попытался встроить простой js скрипт на страницу, но столкнулся с тем что статические файлы приложение отдавать клиенту ни в какую не хочет. 
В лог пишет такую строку:

```
WARN 22292 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

В браузере 405 ошибка
[image]

Ниже мои конфиги:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/main", "/registration", "/static/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/main", true)
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }

}
```

Пробовал убирать мэппинг с корневой папки, но без результата

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
//    @GetMapping("/")
//    public String greeting(Map<String, Object> model) {
//        return "main";
//    }

    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String main(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "main";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String registration() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Ну и разметка вызова скрипта (вызываемый скрипт закомментирован):

```
<div id="app">
    {{ msg }}
</div>
<#--<script>-->
<#--var app = new Vue({-->
    <#--el: '#app',-->
    <#--data: {-->
        <#--msg: '12345'-->
    <#--}-->
<#--})-->
<#--</script>-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/12.js"></script>
```

В чем моя ошибка?

**UPD:**

Структура файлов
(помещал один и тот же скрипт в разные места, но нигде не заработало)

[image]

Comment: Попробуйте без `/static`

Comment: В таком случае код 302 и скрипт все еще не работает

Comment: Прдемонстрируйте развернутую структуру файлов вашего проекта.

Comment: Добавил структуру файлов

Comment: Статические файлы надо исключить из секюрити.